# read json data in php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I've created a valid JSON object in JavaScript:

```
[
    {
        "code": "2F-58S",
        "price": "123,13"
    },
    {
        "code": "2F-58S",
        "price": "123,13"
    }
]
```

I have a problem with reading it in PHP:

```
$productsArr = json_decode($_GET['object']);
foreach($productsArr as $article)
{
    $html .='<td>'.$article->code.'</td>';
    $html .='<td>'.$article->price.'</td></tr>';
}
```

I'm getting an error that `foreach()` loop is not defined as it should be.
What am I missing in here?

EDIT:

It seems that I'm not receiving an entire JSON values with the GET method.
I'm getting something like: `[{"code":"2F-58S","price":"123,13"},{"code":`

EDIT2:

JSON object `break` is happening when reading HTML tags from the object, error is created when you reach this html tag: `<p><strong>EnMotion&nbsp;</strong></p>\n\n<p><strong>impulse</strong></p>`

Comment: are you checking `isset($_GET['object'])`? try dumping the raw value of the GET param, and `var_dump($productsArr);`, too. If the GET param isn't set, your code equates to `foreach(null as $article){}`, which will result in a warning (foreach expects an array)

Comment: How are you submitting the JSON object to the PHP file?

Comment: check that you are getting value in $_GET

Comment: @user123_456: But what do those vals look like in their raw format? And no, `json_encode` is right out

Comment: try to dump the value of $_GET

Comment: @user123_456: and what is the value of `productsJSON` in JS?

Comment: @user123_456: it's not unlikely you're creating a vast request URI, which is always a bad idea. Check your apache logs for 413 errors, and consider using POST (ajax request), and redirect on success instead

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$productsArr = file_get_contents('php://input');
foreach($productsArr as $article)
{
    $html .='<td>'.$article->code.'</td>';
    $html .='<td>'.$article->price.'</td></tr>';
}
```

Comment: file_get_contents('php://input') takes the request payload from POST, not from files

Answer (score 0):

Try true, with json_decode.

```
if(!empty($_GET['object'])){
  $productsArr = json_decode($_GET['object'],true);// this will return array
}
```

### ~K

Working:

```
<?php 
 $a = '[
    {
        "code": "2F-58S",
        "price": "123,13"
    },
    {
        "code": "2F-58S",
        "price": "123,13"
    } ]'; 
 $productsArr = json_decode($a,true); 
 print_r($productsArr); 
 $html = ''; 
 foreach($productsArr as $article) { 
    $html .='<td>'.$article['code'].'</td>';
    $html .='<td>'.$article['price'].'</td></tr>';
    echo $html;
} 
?>
```

**Output:**

```
<td>2F-58S</td><td>123,13</td></tr><td>2F-58S</td><td>123,13</td></tr>
```

Comment: If the data likes like the OP's example, this doesn't solve the problem